# How can i change the background color of each individual div using state in Reactjs by clicking a button?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to change the background color of each div by clicking a button. The way I would like it to work is:

They all start out white. Then click the button and the top div turns blue. Click again the first div turns white second div one turns blue. Click again and the third one turns blue and second turns white.
Click again and the third turns white and first is blue and it keeps going.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Page extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color:"white"
        }
    }
    changeColor = () => {
        if(this.state.color ==="white"){
            this.setState({color:"blue"})
        }
        if (this.state.color === "blue") {
            this.setState({ color: "white" })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="box" style={{background:this.state.color}}></div>
                <div className="box" style={{ background: this.state.color}}></div>
                <div className="box" style={{ background: this.state.color }}></div>
                <button onClick={this.changeColor}>Click me</button>
              </>
        );
    }
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: your question and explanation doesn't match, Do you want change the background color of all `div`s or you want change only one div at time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a count in your state instead of the colour, so you know which div you want to set the background on:

```js
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          count: 0
      }
  }
  changeColor = () => {
    let next = this.state.count + 1;
    if (next === 4) {
      next = 0;
    }
    this.setState({count: next})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="box" style={{ background: this.state.count === 1 ? "blue" : "white" }}>a</div>
        <div className="box" style={{ background: this.state.count === 2 ? "blue" : "white" }}>b</div>
        <div className="box" style={{ background: this.state.count === 3 ? "blue" : "white" }}>c</div>
        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>Click me</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Each div is responsible for setting its own background. I also put a, b, and c in  the divs as they did not display without any content.